# DynamoDBMappingException error

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to run a test in the following spring/dynamoDB app. I'm not exactly sure what the error is trying to tell me, I'm just sure it is a mapping error.

What I'm attempting to do is load an item already said in my AWS Dynamo Database and pull into a string to output in System.out. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "com.ronone")
public class AWSConfig {


    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecreyKey;

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials awsCredentials(){
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecreyKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentials awsCredentials){
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8080", "us-east-2"))
                .build();
        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class CountryController {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB;


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String test(){

        Country testCountry;
        dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
        testCountry = dynamoDBMapper.load(Country.class, "Algeria");
        return "Country was: " + testCountry.getCountryName().toString();

    }
}
```

PrintTrace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: type [class java.util.UUID] is not supported; no conversion from class java.lang.Long
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ConverterMap.getConverter(StandardTypeConverters.java:514) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ConverterMap.access$4800(StandardTypeConverters.java:486) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Scalar.getConverter(StandardTypeConverters.java:312) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters.getConverter(StandardTypeConverters.java:66) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBGeneratedUuid$Generator.<init>(DynamoDBGeneratedUuid.java:61) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardAnnotationMaps.overrideOf(StandardAnnotationMaps.java:436) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardAnnotationMaps.access$500(StandardAnnotationMaps.java:42) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardAnnotationMaps$TypedMap.autoGenerator(StandardAnnotationMaps.java:164) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel$Properties$Immutable.<init>(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:461) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$Bean.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:92) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$Bean.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:86) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.putOrFlatten(StandardBeanProperties.java:217) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.putAll(StandardBeanProperties.java:207) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$BeanMap.<init>(StandardBeanProperties.java:198) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$CachedBeans.getBeans(StandardBeanProperties.java:55) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$CachedBeans.access$100(StandardBeanProperties.java:48) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties.of(StandardBeanProperties.java:42) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$TableBuilder.<init>(StandardModelFactories.java:132) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$TableBuilder.<init>(StandardModelFactories.java:116) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$StandardTableFactory.getTable(StandardModelFactories.java:107) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:393) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:431) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:80) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.235.jar:na]
    at com.ronone.controller.CountryController.test(CountryController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.
```

Comment: What is the structure of `Country` class?

Comment: @Vikdor each country has a hash in their name and a range ID in a unique ID

Comment: That ID seems to be a UUID field. Instead, it should be a String or you should use an implementation of DynamoDBTypeConverter to convert UUID to String and back to UUID (which I think is not required and String should be sufficient)